# What kind of cheap ultrasound speaker would you recommend for basic playback tests?

Tags: hardware, terrestrial, speakers, rodents, ultrasounds

I'd like to test the sound response of some rodents to ultrasounds (~40-100 kHz), but my recording/playback devices (microphone, speaker, soundcard) are for human-hearing range.

**Regarding speakers**, the ultrasound speakers I have found are quite expensive just to test things ([here](https://www.avisoft.com/price-list-ordering-information/) ~700€ +1200€ for the amplifier, [here](https://batsound.com/product/l400-ultrasound-speaker/?currency=EUR) ~1000€ amplifier included), what cheap speakers would you recommend to me for basic behavioral tests? They don't need to be powerful as the speaker can be located relatively close to the rodents.

Answer (score 1):

Not a recommendation, but a suggestion: have you considered using an ultrasonic animal deterrent? A variety of such products can be found on Amazon.com[.au], and some cost a few dozen $AUD, which could be considered 'very cheap'.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I'd need at least an input plug to play back sounds, and I'm not confident enough with electronics to hack a deterrent